Idiomatic expressions for making sarcastic comparisons with other person: translations for ‘otra que’ or ‘ser un poroto’
Consider this situation. I'm playing a football game and one of my teammates eludes all the opponents and scores all on his own. If he is a regular player, I would say with irony one of these two phrases:

¡Otra que Messi! (difficult to translate, literally would be: ‘Well, as we were speaking about Messi...’): Messi does it worse than you
¡Messi es un poroto!: Messi is nothing besides you

I like this example too, is a title of a notice:

Otra que Tevez
Así como Carlos Tevez se negó a jugar en Manchester City, Samuel Eto'o lo hizo con la
selección de Camerún. Con el agravante de convencer a sus compañeros para no presentarse
a jugar un amistoso ante Argelia. El Comité disciplinario sancionó al ex Barcelona con 15
partidos de suspensión.

As you see, the author compared Eto'o with Tevez because both of them decided that they would not play with their national teams, and somehow affirms that ‘Eto'o's behiavor was worse’ (con el agravante de).
Most of the times, both phrases are used with sarcasm, but that's not necessary true. I'm interested specially in translating ‘otra que’ since it's atypical to find an adverb (honestly I don't know how to classify that construction) behind a name. But any idiomatic expression for this counts.
If you want a more detailed explanation, here's an article but you'll have to read Spanish. Regards.

One construction that could be used here is He out-Messied Messi! Doesn't roll off the tongue with every name, but in the political sphere I found both outthatchered thatcher and outblaired blair. There's also "Messi ain't got nothing on you!" (you're at least as good as Messi).

...you could also perhaps say "Talk about Messi! Tevez is right up there with Pele!"

Really? How is this an opinion based question?

It's Off Topic because there is no single "correct" answer - it's an invitation to propose "lists" of possible phrasings. I haven't checked the wording in the Help pages for years, and they do get revised from time to time, but the general principle is a question should admit of one unambiguously correct answer that we can all upvote. That certainly wouldn't apply here.

@FumbleFingers So, how is this quiestion different than the one I did this time. There could be multiple answers, too. In fact, there are multiple ‘correct’ answers. Following that argument, all of my questions should be closed.

It's not a well written question, and not entirely clear what is meant especially if you don't speak Spanish, but it's no more opinion based than other word choice or phrase choice questions, which have been agreed to be allowed.

In addition to the constructions offered in the comments, we can use move over in the imperative in a similar jocular or ironic way.
move over (v.)

To make room, give way; (colloquial) to yield to something more
successful, advanced, up to date, etc. Frequently in imperative.
Move over buckyballs. Now there are new stars in the chemical heavens.
Popular Science December 79/2
[OED online]



Move over Messi and Ronaldo: Antoine was now the best big game player in the world!
Matt Oldfield and Tom Oldfield; Griezmann 
(2019)


"Move over, Einstein: Machines will take it from here"
Justin Mullins; at newscientist.com (16 Mach 2011)


Move over, Newton, there's a new boy in town!"
Paul D'Andrea and ‎Jon
Klein; The Einstein Project (2004)


MOVE OVER, MICHAEL PHELPS!
Elephants are excellent swimmers! In fact, they're the best swimmers
of any land animal—except for professional human swimmers!
Tim
Flannery; Weird, Wild, Amazing! Desert (2022)


You can also find step aside and take a back seat  used this way (the latter less common in the imperative):

Move over Socrates. Step aside Einstein. Take a back seat Descartes.
Blurb for James Labrador; The Extraordinary Sayings of Ordinary People
(2003)


If that's the case, step aside, Einstein, Marcia is about to
unseat you as the world's model of intellectual genius!
Marcia
McFarland; Perfect Glory (2024)

